# Which one is grammatically correct sentence and why?

Tags: grammaticality, articles

1.He discussed murder case with his wife .    2. He discussed the murder case with his wife.        3. He discussed a murder case with his wife.

Answer (score 1):

1 is wrong.

2 is correct IF the context had already specified which case they were discussing.

3 is correct if they were describing some murder case not specified.